# Large LINQ Grouping query, what's happening behind the scenes

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, group-by, parallel-processing

Take the following LINQ query as an example. Please don't comment on the code itself as I've just typed it to help with this question.

The following LINQ query uses a 'group by' and calculates summary information. As you can see there are numerous calculations which are being performed on the data but how efficient is LINQ behind the scenes.

```
var NinjasGrouped = (from ninja in Ninjas 
    group pos by new { pos.NinjaClan, pos.NinjaRank } 
    into con 
    select new NinjaGroupSummary 
    { 
        NinjaClan = con.Key.NinjaClan, 
        NinjaRank = con.Key.NinjaRank, 
        NumberOfShoes = con.Sum(x => x.Shoes), 
        MaxNinjaAge = con.Max(x => x.NinjaAge), 
        MinNinjaAge = con.Min(x => x.NinjaAge), 
        ComplicatedCalculation = con.Sum(x => x.NinjaGrade) != 0 
        ? con.Sum(x => x.NinjaRedBloodCellCount)/con.Sum(x => x.NinjaDoctorVisits)
        : 0,
    ListOfNinjas = con.ToList() 
    }).ToList();
```

1. How many times is the list of 'Ninjas' being iterated over in order to calculate each of the values?
2. Would it be faster to employ a foreach loop to speed up the execution of such a query?
3. Would adding '.AsParallel()' after Ninjas result in any performance improvements?
4. Is there a better way of calculating summery information for List?

Any advice is appreciated as we use this type of code throughout our software and I would really like to gain a better understanding of what LINQ is doing underneath the hood (so to speak). Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: It's important to know if `Ninjas` is an `IEnumerable` or an `IQueryable`. If former, it would be enumerated exactly once. If latter, there is no enumeration to speak of; the query is compiled into, e.g., SQL directly; the grouping is done by the DBMS and the only thing enumerated in C# is the resultset.

Comment: 'Ninjas' is an in memory list, IEnumerable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this is a LINQ to Objects query:

- `Ninjas` is only iterated over once; the groups are built up into internal concrete lists, which you're then iterating over multiple times (once per aggregation).
- Using a `foreach` loop almost certainly wouldn't speed things up - you might benefit from cache coherency a bit more (as each time you iterate over a group it'll probably have to fetch data from a higher level cache or main memory) but I very much doubt that it would be significant. The increase in pain in implementing it probably *would* be significant though :)
- Using `AsParallel` *might* speed things up - it looks pretty easily parallelizable. Worth a try...
- There's not a much better way for LINQ to Objects, to be honest. It would be nice to be able to perform the aggregation as you're grouping, and Reactive Extensions would allow you to do something like that, but for the moment this is probably the simplest approach.

You might want to have a look at the [`GroupBy` post in my Edulinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby.aspx) for more details on a *possible* implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jon, indeed this is a LINQ to Objects query. Can you expand on your comment 'Using a foreach loop almost certainly wouldn't speed things up', I don't see how this is true if internal concrete lists are being iterated (potentially) numerous times?

Comment: @Belinda: Well the you're processing the same amount of data - you'd just be keeping track of things slightly differently. I guess you'd benefit from cache coherency a bit - but I very much doubt that it would be significant. Will edit to make that clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wouldn't a single for loop over `con` speed things up since it would be able to calculate all the aggregate values in one go? (Now every aggregate needs to iterate `con` by itself)

Comment: @Magnus: The last bullet point is trying to address that to some extent (although your point goes further). Iterating over `con` once would be more cache friendly, but the code to do the aggregation would be significantly more complex. Importantly, iterating over `con` multiple times *doesn't* need to consult the source multiple times - the values in each group are just a list, effectively.